# Why pdf thumbnails cause page bad looking?

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-extensions

When I use Mediawiki's `CommentStreams` extension with code below:

```
== Guide ==
[[File:TerraformingMars.pdf|page=1|thumb|right|راهنمای فارسی - سایت: بازی نوین، مترجم: نیما مسقدی]]

== Comments ==
<comment-streams/>
```

Why does it look bad as here: [image]
But if I move Guide section below Comments it works fine? How to fix it? It seems pdf thumbnailing has problem with anything after it, and it must be the last one?

Comment: Try to add something before your tag, like &nbsp;<comment-streams/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has float positioning so the content that follows it will be laid out alongside it. If you don't like that, don't float it (use e.g. `center` instead of `thumb`) or put something like Wikipedia's [{{clear}}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Clear) template after it.